# require-less throwing lessc error in firefox

Tags: firefox, requirejs, less

So I'm working with RequireJS and BackboneJS. I can get everything to work fine in Chrome but when I load up in Firefox I'm getting that lessc is not defined. Obviously pulling out the less files will prevent the error from occurring. Does anyone have any ideas why require is unable to load lessc in firefox but its doing fine in chrome?

Screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/WenocFdCA0V

Video w/ lessc not being defined in Chrome but not Firefox
http://screencast.com/t/ac96qZrpQb3R

Let me know what other info may be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Seth

Comment: Known less bug, it seems: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1521

Comment: Thats actually for less... not require-less

Comment: require-less does contain less, and therefore has the same issue. https://github.com/guybedford/require-less/blob/master/lessc.js#L5421-L5425

Comment: I can run less outside of require and its running fine...

Comment: It even says so in your screenshot: "`loadStyles` is not defined" ;)

Comment: do you know if replacing lessc with less1.5 would fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less.js` is [broken](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1521), because it uses `loadStyles` before it defines it, and Firefox stopped hoisting functions according to the spec. There are probably more such mistakes, but this is the first one that is triggered during execution. Please note that the minified version is not affected because of the minification rewriting the code.

`less-require` is similarly broken, as it contains `less.js` and therefore contains the same bug.

You might want to replace `lessc.js` in `require-less` with the 1.5 beta or master version of `less.js` to work around this, or wait for upstream to officially release it and `require-less` to pick it up.

However, it appears that `lessc.js` is a modified version, so it isn't likely as easy as replacing the file. You would need to merge the changes back.

It might be easier just to move the affected `latedefs` around until it runs correctly instead of upgrading to a later `less.js` version.

Comment: So I replaced lessc.js with less-1.5.0-b2.min.js (https://raw.github.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.5.0-b2.min.js) and its compiling